# SQL Calculate percentage

Tags: sql

I have four columns in a table.

```
+------+-------+------------+---------------+
| Year | Month | OrderCount | SaleCount2015 |
+------+-------+------------+---------------+
| 2015 |   1   |    876     |     453       |
| 2015 |   2   |    764     |     548       |
| 2015 |   3   |    951     |     632       |
| 2015 |   4   |    ...     |     ...       |
+------+-------+------------+---------------+
```

I want to calculate the SalePercentage for every month, but the results return 0s. I use the following SQL query.

```
Select Year, 
       Month, 
       OrderCount, 
       SaleCount, 
       SaleCount/OrderCount AS SalePercentage
From TableName
```

Could anyone tell me the problem with this query? Thanks.

Comment: for every row percentage is returning 0 ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: are you using `sql server`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i think this could happen when using oracle with toad but when values loaded to code form data base it will display floating point numbers only try once,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Year, Month, OrderCount, SaleCount,
    CAST (SaleCount AS FLOAT) / CAST(OrderCount AS FLOAT) AS SalePercentage
FROM TableName
```

You are using integer division so `5/10` will be `0`, but `5.0/10.0` will be `0.5`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sql server`

If you divide integers then you are getting integer as the result;

Convert one or both column value to `float` or `double`

```
cast(SaleCount as float) /OrderCount AS SalePercentage
```

or

```
(SaleCount*1.0)/OrderCount AS SalePercentage
```

Its better to check whether `OrderCount` is `zero`

```
case when OrderCount = 0 then 0
else (SaleCount*1.0)/OrderCount end AS SalePercentage
```

**Demo** [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9930f/4)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Money** type for financial calculations...

```
SELECT Year, Month, OrderCount, SaleCount, IIF(OrderCount  = 0, 0, CAST(SaleCount AS MONEY)/CAST(OrderCount AS MONEY)) AS SalePercentage FROM TableName
```

Comment: Money and IIF are product specific functionality - for which dbms? (No dbms specified in question.)

Answer (score 0):

No matter which data base you are using. Your results are not showing percentage but a fraction. If you will multiply this by 100 it will be resolved:

```
Select Year, 
       Month, 
       OrderCount, 
       SaleCount, 
       (SaleCount*100)/OrderCount AS SalePercentage
From TableName
```